# Typescript Array of Object sort does not work in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript

I try to sort an array of objecs.
When I try it in the console (Firefox and Chrome) it works:

```
let x = [{"id":1,"name":"Adam","levelFinished":2,"avgTime":150,"deathCount":5},{"id":2,"name":"Bert","levelFinished":2,"avgTime":300,"deathCount":2}]
x.sort((a, b) => { console.log(a.avgTime - b.avgTime); return a.avgTime - b.avgTime })
```

The result is "Adam"-object and after "Bert"-object.

When I try to do the same thing in Next.js 13 in a React component it's always first "Bert" and after "Adam" no matter if "a.avgTime - b.avgTime" is positiv or negativ.

I used this code in my component:

```
const contentObject = getContentObjectForRanking();
console.log(JSON.stringify(contentObject));
const sortByTime = contentObject.sort((a, b) => { console.log(a.avgTime - b.avgTime); return a.avgTime - b.avgTime });
console.log(sortByTime);
```

The "let x = ..." from above is the output of the first "console.log", so the objects are the same.
The sort is copy paste and in both cases are the same.
The second "console.log" in the React code will always return the wrong order.

Next I tried to copy the "let x = [...]" (first code block) in my React component and it works. The "x" object is sorted correctly while the "contentObject" is not. I logged both to the console and they look the same but "==" says they are not.
The log of first "x" and second "contentObject".

Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { id: 1, name: "Adam", levelFinished: 2, … }
​​
avgTime: 150
​​
deathCount: 5
​​
id: 1
​​
levelFinished: 2
​​
name: "Adam"
​​
: Object { … }
​
1: Object { id: 2, name: "Bernd", levelFinished: 2, … }
​​
avgTime: 300
​​
deathCount: 2
​​
id: 2
​​
levelFinished: 2
​​
name: "Bernd"
​​
: Object { … }
​
length: 2
​
: Array []

Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { id: 2, name: "Bernd", levelFinished: 2, … }
​​
avgTime: 300
​​
deathCount: 2
​​
id: 2
​​
levelFinished: 2
​​
name: "Bernd"
​​
: Object { … }
​
1: Object { id: 1, name: "Adam", levelFinished: 2, … }
​​
avgTime: 150
​​
deathCount: 5
​​
id: 1
​​
levelFinished: 2
​​
name: "Adam"
​​
: Object { … }
​
length: 2
​
: Array []

I have no idea whats the difference between them.

Best regards

---

Edits:
Thanks for the comments.

- I noticed short after that Objects comparison works not like this. Thanks :)
- "x" is the copied version of "JSON.stringify(contentObject)" and the sort works for "x". So it doesn't matter if I return -150 or -1. I even tried that approach with returning -1, 1 and 0 but no difference at all. contentObject isn't sorted.
- I'm pretty sure React has no impact on sort but not 100% sure.

Because "x" is the copy of stringify of "contentObject" I tried to stringify and parse the contentObject but sort doesn't work on that also.

For the following block the first and the second work but the third not:

```
let test = JSON.stringify(contentObject)
let test2 = JSON.parse(test);
console.log(test2.sort((a, b) => {return a.avgTime - b.avgTime }));
         
let x = [{"id":1,"name":"Adam","levelFinished":2,"avgTime":150,"deathCount":5},{"id":2,"name":"Bernd","levelFinished":2,"avgTime":300,"deathCount":2}]
console.log(x.sort((a, b) => {return a.avgTime - b.avgTime }));

contentObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(contentObject));
console.log(contentObject.sort((a, b) => {return a.avgTime - b.avgTime }));
```

Comment: JavaScript won't do deep comparison with `==`, it will just do a reference comparison. You can use lodash for this: `_.isEqual(x, contentObject)`

Comment: `sortByTime = contentObject.sort(` is useless, sort modifies the array in place. Also despite overly-clever snippets you see online the correct return values from the sort callback are 1, -1, or 0, not -150. Last but not least I'm *reasonably* sure React does not modify how something as basic as sort on arrays works, you shouldn't be seeing a different result *just* because of React...also also, in addition to what Irfanullah Jan mentioned about reference vs value equality console.log of an object is a *live view* of that object, not a snapshot at the point in time the log occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I edit my original Post to answer and to bring in a new observation.